# SharePoint 2013 - How do I add a button to a page that opens a list form when pressed?

Tags: list, button, sharepoint-2013

I am currently working within SharePoint 2013 and was wondering if there was a way to create a button on a home page that when pressed, opens a list form in a modal window? (or in a non modal window).

I understand the method of using "Embed code" to code a button; however, it doesn't seem to allow me to link it to a list form, or edit what the button actually does.

**Example:**

1. An employee lands on the home page and wants to initiate a Purchase Request through the company.
2. The employee clicks on a button labeled "Click here to submit a Purchase Request".
3. After clicking, the Purchase Request form opens from the Purchase Request list (pre-created).

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this in a CEWP to redirect to the new item form:

```
<button onclick="formRedirect(); return false;">New Form</button>
<script> 
    function formRedirect() { 
        window.location = "/test/Lists/LinkList/NewForm.aspx" 
    } 
</script>
```

To display it in Modal form you will need to use the NewItem2 JS function:

```
<button onclick="NewItem2(event, &quot;https://Your.SP.Site/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=8&amp;ListId=%7B59E6FE0C%2D02C6%2D4B00%2D9B6A%2D87116A2DF594%7D&amp;RootFolder=&quot;); return false;">New Form</button>
```

To get this to work you will need the list web part on the page where the button is located, though it can be hidden from view by setting th chrome to none and minimizing it.  You can copy the function from the new item button in the list you wish to display, it is stored as an 'OnClick' property.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to this but I just figured how to do this for the "Upload Document" for a document library. It took me a while but I stumbled upon it through trial and error using F12. I will provide both script for a "LIST and LIBRARY" form.

FOR A LIST:

```
<a href="#" onclick="openDialog('YourSiteURL/Lists/YourListName/NewForm.aspx');">
   <img src="YourSiteImageURL" alt="NameofYourImage">
</a>

<script>
  function openDialog(pageUrl) { 
  var options = {
  url: pageUrl,
  title: 'NameofYourForm', /* Enter the name you want for your form */
  allowMaximize: false,
  showClose: true,
  width: 1225, /* Modify for your needs */
  height: 800 /* Modify for your needs */
};
  SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);       
}
</script>
```

FOR A LIBRARY:

This is for use with a button:

```
<a class="ms-addnew" id="idHomePageNewDocument" onclick='NewItem2(event, "YourSiteURL/_layouts/15/Upload.aspx?List={YourListID}&amp;RootFolder="); return false;' href="YourSiteURL/_layouts/15/Upload.aspx?List={SameListID}&amp;RootFolder=" target="_self" data-viewctr="702">
   <img src="URLforYourButtonImage" alt="NameofYourButton">
</a>
```

This is for use with text:

```
<a class="ms-addnew" id="idHomePageNewDocument" onclick='NewItem2(event, "YourSiteURL/_layouts/15/Upload.aspx?List={YourListID}&amp;RootFolder="); return false;' href="YourSiteURL/_layouts/15/Upload.aspx?List={SameListID}&amp;RootFolder=" target="_self" data-viewctr="702">Add document
</a>
```